# Hiding folders and its content from application grid

Tags: 18.04

I'd like to know how to hide - unhide a folder with its application content from application grid.
I don't want to empty or delete it, just hide. The reason is: I am preparing a computer for someone with low IT skills and don't want to confuse her with all those unnecessary applications like dconf editor etc. I put all these in a folder in application grid and would like to hide it. However, I'd like to unhide this folder when doing maintenance, updates etc.
18.04 LTS installed.
I tried to hide the folder but in this case all apps flooded the grid. Obviously no point of deleting apps from the folder to make it disappear.
Any solution to keep the neat and tidy grid and just hide folders when they are not needed?
Really appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can hide individual application icons, there is no possibility to hide a folder in the Application overview. There are a couple of workarounds you could consider:

**Workaround 1. Delete and restore the folder with a script**

Configuration for the folders in the application grid is stored in gsettings, under `/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/`. You could write a script that saves the folder settings (`dconf dump ...`), then deletes the data under `/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/`.A restore script can then reload these keys (`dconf load ...`).

**Workaround 2. Just hide the applications you do not want to reveal**

Copy the `.desktop` files of the applications you want to hide to `~/.local/share/applications`. These will take precedence over the system wide installed copies. Then add or set the line `Hidden=true`. Also this can be scripted (e.g., if the line is already there: `sed -i 's/Hidden=false/Hidden=true/' *.desktop`.

**Workaround 3. Hide everything and use the command line as administrator**

As administrator, you of course could just hide the applications, and delete the folders in the account. You can speedily load the "hidden" utilities using the command line (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>dconf-e<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to load dconf-editor). Then you do not need to bother about scripting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, reassuring that no such hiding option. I'll try your workaround options. Thanks again.